# I want to initialize an array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

when I click new button, I have to clear all information like this.
from

```
testInfo:{
        test1: 12
        test2: "test2"
        ...
        test99: "test99"
    }
```

to

```
testInfo:{
        test1: 0 (or "")
        test2: ""
        ...
        test99: ""
    }
```

any good idea?
thanks.

Comment: Store `testInfo` in the state object, when handling click just `setState()` with the desired data.

Comment: In general, outside of an framework: Quick `for` loop, assemble property name as a string, using the loop counter … and then assign "" or 0 …?

Comment: create a default object with `''` values and reset the variable with default object on click.

Comment: Why not use an array instead of using keys suffixed with consecutive numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try creating an object from mapped entries like so:

```js
const testInfo = {
  test1: 12,
  test2: "test2",
  test99: "test99",
}

console.log(Object.fromEntries(Object.keys(testInfo).map(key => [key, ""])));
```

---

```
const toReset = testInfo =>
  Object.fromEntries(Object.keys(testInfo).map(key => [key, '']));

setState({ testInfo: toReset(someState) });
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
for (const key in testInfo) {
  testInfo[key] = typeof testInfo[key] === 'number' ? 0 : '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The question uses object syntax, but I think you might want an array.

And if you need pre-created integer properties then you can do this:

```js
const a = [...Array(99)] // 99 / whatever
console.log(JSON.stringify(a))
```

And if you really don't want an array:

```js
const o = {...[...Array(99)]} // 99 / whatever
console.log(o)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the object ***is not*** part of your React state:

```js
// Initialize
const testInfo = { test1: 12, test2: "test2", test99: "test99" };

// Update
for (const key in testInfo) {
  testInfo[key] = "";
}
console.log(testInfo);
```

If the object ***is*** part of your React state then you always need to create a fresh object from scratch, and set that as the new state.

Example using *React Hooks*:

```js
// Initialize
const [testInfo, setTestInfo] = useState({ test1: 12, test2: "test2", test99: "test99" });

// Update
const newInfo = testInfo.clone();
for (const key in newInfo) {
  newInfo[key] = "";
}
setTestInfo(newInfo);
```

Answer (score -2):

Keep a state for your formInfo and a default state value in a constant.

```
const defaultTestInfo = {
      test1: 0,
      test2: "",
      test99: "",
    }

const resetFormInfo = () => {
  this.setState({ testInfo: defaultTestInfo })
}
```

And pass `resetFormInfo` in your button `onClick`

Comment: Why would you keep a 99 entries default value?

Comment: @MichleLi So use an array instead.

Comment: There are 99 other values as well.

Comment: yeah, I didnt noticed the number of entries. not feasible in that case

Comment: space complexity is mostly preferred over time complexity. even if there are 255 entries a `json/js exporting object` file can be created and used for the same.